# Why does the same program look different when run in Windows and Linux?

Tags: python, linux, windows, tkinter

I have written a simple Python application to measure time from a certain event. Everything works fine, but the fact that it looks completely different on two different operating systems gives me a bit of a headache. Can I do something and why is that happening? I mean, at the end, the code is the same.

```
# str8.py
#   Program to measure time from a certain event

from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime

class FormatLabel(Label):

    # A new type of Label widget that allows both text and textvariable

    def __init__(self, master = None, **kwargs):

        self.textvariable = kwargs.pop('textvariable', StringVar(master))
        self.text = kwargs.pop('text', '{}')
        self.textvariable.trace('w', self.update_text)

        Label.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

    def update_text(self, *args):

        self.config(text = self.text.format(self.textvariable.get()))

class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None, **kwargs):

        Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        lbl = Label(self, text = 'You have been STR8 for:\n', font = 'Verdana 8 bold')
        lbl.grid(row=0, sticky=W)

        self.counters = dict()
        measurements = [ 'Years', 'Weeks', 'Days', 'Hours', 'Minutes', 'Seconds' ]

        for i, measurement in enumerate(measurements):

            self.counters[measurement] = DoubleVar()

            lbl = FormatLabel(self,
                              text = measurement + ": {:.2f}", # set the rounding here
                              textvariable = self.counters[measurement],
                              font = 'Verdana 8')
            lbl.grid(row = i + 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

            self.counters[measurement].set(0)

        btn = Button(self,
                     text = 'EXIT',
                     font = 'Verdana 8',
                     height = 1,
                     width = 19,
                     command = quit)
        btn.grid(row = 7, column = 0)

        self.increment()

    def increment(self):

        event = datetime(2017, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0)
        today = datetime.now()

        str8 = (today - event).total_seconds()

        self.counters['Minutes'].set(str8 / 60.)
        self.counters['Hours'].set(str8 / 3600.)
        self.counters['Seconds'].set(str8)
        self.counters['Days'].set(str8 / (3600. * 24))
        self.counters['Weeks'].set(str8 / (3600. * 24 * 7))
        self.counters['Years'].set(str8 / (3600. * 24 * 7 * 52))

        self.after(1000, self.increment)

def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.pack()
    root.title("STR8")
    root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Images:

- [Linux Mint XFCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtBuC.png)
- [Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Jt2.png)

Comment: Tkinter (and tk in general) use the native GUI building blocks of your operating system's window manager.  I doubt that there is much you can do about it.

Comment: They look different for the same reason that Windows and Linux generally look different. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @zondo You should actually worry about it, because certain parameters in one OS may not take effect (at all) as in other OSes.

Comment: Yeah, I am worrying because the title is not shown in Windows, and button is somehow distorted as well.

Comment: _completely_ different? They look _barely_ different to me. Same buttons, same words, same organization, more or less the same size...

Comment: Don't split hairs with me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tkinter isn't designed to look the same on every platform. To the contrary, it is specifically designed to look different on each platform. It is designed to *work* the same but not necessarily *look* the same. Whenever possible it uses the underlying OS's widget toolkit to draw the widgets (ie: you'll get OSX-looking buttons on OSX, windows-looking buttons on windows, etc.)

The main goal of tkinter was to have the same code run on all platforms and work the same, but adhere to platform guidelines as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. So, I can't do anything?

Comment: @venom1337: that depends on your definition of "anything".  You can change the font, and you might be able to change the colors (except on OSX), and you can change the amount of spacing. There are a dozen or so attributes to a label. Just experiment. Normally you shouldn't want to do anything -- you should make your app look appropriate for the platform it is running on. Windows users don't want to see an app that looks like linux.

Comment: @venom1337 You *shouldn't* do anything. Two windows on the same system that look different are very jarring. There are always a *couple* of programs who think they're so important they can violate the rules ... or that just use an obsolete toolkit.